# Find TFS Build Request by ID

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build

In TFS every requested build has a Request ID, for example:

[image: build request id]

Is it possible in Visual Studio 2015 (or in TFS Web Browser) to query build requests by ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, seems you are talking about the request ID which build history "View Summary" tab shows.

It's not able to directly query this through Visual Studio or Web Portal.

However, you could use client API to fetch this. On the BuildDetail object: BuildDetail.RequestIds.Item(0)

There is also a [BuildRequest Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/gg215440(v%3Dvs.120)).

> *Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.BuildRequest*
>
> ***BatchId*** Gets or sets the batch ID for this request. Requests with matching batch IDs are started together in a single build up to a
>   maximum batch size configured on the Build Definition.